# What would happen if two branes collided and stuck together?

Tags: string-theory, branes

There is a theory that the universe began when two "branes" bumped each other, creating the energy that sparked the beginning of our universe. What if instead of separating, they actually stuck, causing the physics of one brane to predominate under some circumstances and the physics of the other brane, in other circumstances? How would we be able to tell which physical phenomenon belonged to which brane?

Answer (score 0):

For the branes to collide, they must have been initially moving. Except in the extremely brief period in which the branes share the same position, they would not be subject to the electromagnetic (or strong or weak) interactions; in fact, gravity would pull them together faster. So although 'sticky' branes would be cool, as far as I know, they are  probably non-existent. But then again, string theory is a rapidly progressive field (no, not [that](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_(physics)) kind of field) and new progress is made all the time. Anyway, I hope I helped you with your question!

Comment: Yeah I kind of figured that branes would most likely repel each other, or they'd just collapse on each other. I read a description ones of strings having either one or both ends stuck to a particular brane and it reminded me of how Velcro hooks and loops look. So I got a picture of one brane composed of hooks and the other composed of loops, coming together like Velcro. The force holding them together would be purely mechanical.